# Unable to determine if the computer '<CLUSTER-NAME>' exists in the domain - New-Cluster cmdlet

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, staf

I am trying to run the `New-Cluster` command via staf to create a cluster on (Windows server 2012 R2, having `failovercluster` role enabled) and PowerShell version is 3.0.

Tried 2 different ways but none of it is working for me.
When I am passing session parameter to `Invoke-Command`, it's able to find `New-Cluster` cmdlet, but when I try without session, it is not able to find the cmdlet.

Here is the snippet of both methods:

1. Staf "start shell command" way:
   When I use this method, I encounter the error as seen below:

   ```
   staf <Server-IP> process START SHELL COMMAND :187:Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock
   ```

   Error I get is as seen below:

   > New-Cluster : The term 'New-Cluster' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
2. Using PSSESSION way:

   ```
   staf <Server-IP> process START SHELL  COMMAND :221:$ps = New-PSSession; Invoke-Command -session $ps -ScriptBlock
   ```

   `New-Cluster` command executes, but it fails with error as seen below:

   ```
   New-Cluster : Unable to determine if the computer '<CLUSTER-NAME>' exists in
   the domain '<DOMAIN-NAME>'.
   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (New-Cluster : U...XXXXXXXX'.:String) [], RemoteException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
       + PSComputerName        : localhost

   An operations error occurred.
   At C:\XXXXXX.ps1:7 char:1
   + New-Cluster -Name $cluster -Node $nodes -StaticAddress $staticaddress
   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Cluster], ClusterCmdletException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : New-Cluster,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.NewClusterCommand
   ```

I don't want to use session parameter, is there any way by which we can use the non-default modules for remote command invocation?
Can someone please suggest if I am missing any needed input or please suggest if I should try some other method to attain the expected result.

Comment: Did you `Import-Module FailoverClusters` in the 1st approach?

Comment: When I use Import-Module in 1st approach, I get exactly same error as seen in approach 2. i.e.`        New-Cluster : Unable to determine if the computer '<ClusterName>' exists in the domain`

Comment: Can you create a cluster via GUI tools? This might be a permissions problem too, refer to [cluster troubleshooting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clustering/2012/05/07/how-to-troubleshoot-create-cluster-failures-in-windows-server-2012/).

Comment: From GUI it works perfectly fine, also when I execute the cmdlet locally it works as expected. Problem is when I execute same cmdlet via STAF ( using Domain Administrator credentials) it throws error as mentioned in case 2 above.

Answer (score 0):

The main points here are as follows:

1. The computers which you want to create a WSFC from, must be part of a domain.
2. Importantly, the `New-Cluster` command should be run as a user belonging to a domain, instead of a local account.

Run the powershell script as a domain account:

`Import-Module FailoverClusters
New-Cluster -Name SomeCluster -Node <NodeName>`